# How can I take variable "data" from Routes in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

Could you give me an example how to get data from Routes. [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' } // <--- How to use this data?
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Thank you

Comment: In the linked page there is a section with: 'The data property in the third route is a place to store arbitrary data associated with this specific route. The data property is accessible within each activated route. Use it to store items such as page titles, breadcrumb text, and other read-only, static data. You'll use the resolve guard to retrieve dynamic data later in the guide.'. DV for lack of self research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ActivatedRoute` in your component/service constructors.

For example:

```
public class MyAppComponent{
data: any;   

constructor(route: ActivatedRoute){
      this.data = route.snapshot.data;
   }
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes/).